# (continue , break) (equality operator , inequality operator) in this Javascript example?

Tags: javascript

I wonder what is the difference between (!==) and (===) in this example, and what is the difference between break and continue??!
In this example I thought that it would print out only the strings, but it prints out every data type except strings.
I know the use of (!== and ===) but in this example it seems strange for me.
Please give an explanation of the use of (!== and ===) also (continue and break) in this example.

```
var array = [1, 2, "hello", true];


for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(typeof array[i] === "string") continue;

    console.log(array[i]);
};
```

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave if the typeof element is String it will not execute rest of statements in loop but continue with the next iteration. If there would have been break it will break out of loop and not execute any further iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) keyword causes the loop to move forward to the next iteration without executing any of the statements in the loop body after it.

`===` is used for strict equality comparison, i.e. two values are only considered the same if they are of the same type and have the same value (no type coercion is done).

The code you have shown is checking if the array element at each index is a string and if so, it is moving on to the next iteration of the loop without printing it.

The code can be rewritten as follows:

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(typeof array[i] !== "string") console.log(array[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it will continue the execution to the next iteration if the type is equal to the string.
But the array has only one element with type string because of this it prints the other 3 elements.

1. Equal to the operator(===) is a strict comparison operator. It checks/compare type of data with its content.
2. Not (!) - It just inverts the operation, in your case, it checks for not equal to(!==)
3. Continue - continue keyword will take you to the next iteration by skipping any lines of code below it.
4. Break - break keyword will take you to out of the loop by skipping any further iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helped but I still need to check more information about this topic c: